# BitmapImage won't load Image

Tags: wpf, vb.net, image, uri, bitmapimage

I am trying to load an image from the web, but it doesn't seem to work with all URi.

```
    Dim tURI As Uri

    tURI = New Uri("http://www.grimmy.com/images/MGG_Archive/MGG_2016/MGG-2016-08-01.gif")
    'tURI = New Uri("http://assets.amuniversal.com/e91ec9c016c20134707c005056a9545d")

    Dim src As BitmapImage = New BitmapImage()
    src.BeginInit()
    src.UriSource = tURI
    src.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad
    src.EndInit()

    If src.IsDownloading = True Then
        Debug.Print("still downloading")
        AddHandler src.DownloadCompleted, AddressOf ImageDownloadCompleted
    Else
        Image1.Source = src
    End If
```

I use the src.DownloadCompleted to load it to Image1.Source=src
It also works with the 2nd tURI but not the first.  Both, if pasted into a browser work fine.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `UriKind.Relative` doesn't make sense on an absolute URI.

Comment: Note also that the `DownloadCompleted` handler is only called when the `IsDownloading` property was `true` after `EndInit`. Otherwise the image is loaded immediately.

Comment: @Clemens It doesn't' matter.  If i remove UriKind.Relative, i get the same results.

Comment: @Clemens  I am using the download complete handler just to track where the problem is.  I have put in the image1.source=src in this block and removed the handlers all together, but it still doesn't work.  The weird part is one tURI works while the other doesn't no matter what changes listed above are made.

Comment: i made changes to the code to address comments above, but the results are the same.